# __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'Value'

Tags: python

I don't understand what is wrong. I keep getting that I'm missing a required positional argument.

```
class CoinToss(object):

    def __init__(self, flip, ID_Num, Value):
        self.flip = flip
        self.ID_Num = ID_Num
        self.Value = Value

    def Flip(self):
        """
        Method is important in determining the number of flips and simulating the coin
        """
        data = []
        Num_flip = int(input("how many times do you want to flip the coin? :"))
        print("the ball at the start: ball: d%, state: d% value: d% " %(self.ID_Num))
        for i in range(Num_flip):
            self.flip = self.flip = 1
            if randint(0,1) == 0:
                self.Value = self.Value + 1
                data.append(self.value)

            else:
                self.Value = self.Value - 1
                data.append(self.Value)
```

Comment: You're instantiating class `CoinToss` in a wrong way by not providing all required arguments. Just check how many arguments you're passing to it, you're missing one.

Comment: i cant find which arguements im passing to it. a i missing something simple?

Comment: Where are you creating a `CoinToss` object in the first place? I'm going to guess you misunderstood how Python initializers work, and did `CoinToss.__init__(x, y, z)` (which doesn't implicitly create an instance and pass it as `self`), when you should do `CoinToss(x, y, z)` which creates the instance then passes it as the first argument implicitly.

Comment: There is also some confusing design here. You pass `flip` to the initializer, but you the class seems to be intended for performing flips; `self.flip` seems to, at best, indicate whether a flip has occurred (it's set to `1` in `Flip`), but requiring the caller to pass it means that the value is not useful; they could have said it flipped when it didn't.

Comment: im calling it in the main             
            else: #for tails
                self.Value = self.Value - 1
                data.append(self.Value)
            print("after flip: %d, ball: %d, state: %d, value: %d" % (i, self.ID_Num, ))
        self.Value = data
        print(self.Value)
def main():
    coin = CoinToss(1, 100)
    coin.flip()
main()

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, when you use `CoinToss`, you call it with only 2 arguments, `flip` and `ID_NUM`.  This would cause an error, because you did not provide `CoinToss.__init__()` with the required `Value` argument.

Comment: how would i provide the arguement value?

Comment: I'm not sure what this code does, but it looks like you should provide it with either 0 or 1 depending on whether you want heads or tails.  By the way, `if randint(0,1) == 0:
                self.Value = self.Value + 1
                data.append(self.value)` appends `self.value` which does not exist.  It should be `data.append(self.Value)`.  Also, the first line of your for loop is `self.flip = self.flip = 1`.  It could be simplified to `self.flip = 1`.